# Auto refresh pivot made off of Data Model

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet and I created a sub function (please see below) to make a call to update specific pivot tables. One particular pivot table ("DataModel") has text as values, so, when I created that pivot table I added it to the data model then did a "Add Measure" and created a line code `=CONCATENATEX(DataModel,[DataValue],”, “)` so I can pivot on the text value.

Anyway, when I run the code below, it updates all the pivot tables I want except for the one made from the data model. Does anyone know how I can use Excel VBA to automate the pivot table made from the data model?

---- Call to module ---

```
Call RefreshPivots("DataModel")

---- Excel VBA Code ---

Public Sub RefreshPivots(ByVal sheetName As String)
Dim sheetExists As Boolean

    sheetExists = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetName Then sheetExists = True
    Next ws

    If sheetExists Then
        Sheets(sheetName).Visible = True
        Sheets(sheetName).Activate

        For Each pivotTab In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
            pivotTab.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next pivotTab
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `pivotTab.RefreshTable` instead to refresh your pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RefreshTable method of the PivotTable object instead.

By the way, the pivot table worksheet does not need to be visible in order to refresh the pivot table.

Also, it's considered good programming practice to follow the 'Dedication of Duty' principle.  It basically says that a function should be dedicated to do one thing, and nothing else.

So, for example, `RefreshPivots` should only refresh the pivot tables.  Checking whether the worksheet exists should be done before calling your function to update the pivot tables.

I have re-written your code accordingly...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim worksheetName As String
    worksheetName = "DataModel"

    If Not WorksheetExists(worksheetName) Then
        MsgBox "'" & worksheetName & "' not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    RefreshWorksheetPivots worksheetName

    'make worksheet visible, if so desired

End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal worksheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) = UCase(worksheetName) Then 'case-insensitive comparison
            WorksheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ws

    WorksheetExists = False

End Function

Public Sub RefreshWorksheetPivots(ByVal worksheetName As String)

    Dim pt As PivotTable

    For Each pt In Worksheets(worksheetName).PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @domenic I'll try that and post my results. The help is very much appreciated!